# How to set an UIView subclass from a framework as a storyboard custom class?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, swift2, xcode7

I have an UIScrollView subclass defined in an external framework.
If I create instances of this class in code, it works as expected.
If I try to set this class as a custom class on an UIScrollView in Scoryboard, it's not listed in available custom classes. If I set it, when I check the object's class it's an UIScrollView (so it doesn't allow to call methods of the subclass).

This happens in a Swift 2.0 project targetting iOS 8.1 (Xcode7)
The framework is using Swift 2.0 too and targetting iOS 8.0
The framework is included manually in the project (copy paste + add to Embedded Binaries)

Hope it's clear enough :D

Answer (score 9):

You must specify a module together with class.

In this example we use class `MyCustomScrollView` from the framework `MyScrollViews.framework`.

[image]

Comment: .What about Objective-c give me error "Unknown class"